# Can't write HDF5 file with vector bigger than 2^13

Tags: c++, hdf5

I'm using C++ & HDF5 to write a file. But run into problems with it. This is the code I use:

```
void fileRead::writeFile(string name, const vector<double>* data) {
int dimn = data->size();

hsize_t dim[1] = {data->size()}; //-> 2^13!!!

hid_t sid = H5Pcreate(H5P_DATASET_CREATE);
hid_t didProp = H5Screate_simple(1,dim,NULL);
H5Pset_layout(sid, H5D_COMPACT);

hid_t did = H5Dcreate(fid, name.c_str(),H5T_IEEE_F64LE, didProp, H5P_DEFAULT, sid,H5P_DEFAULT);
H5Dwrite (did, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, &(data->at(0)));
H5Dclose(did);

H5Sclose(didProp);
H5Pclose(sid);
}
```

But this gives me this error message:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.10) thread 0:   #000: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5D.c line 170 in H5Dcreate2(): unable to create dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to initialize object   #001: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5Dint.c line 439 in H5D__create_named(): unable to create and link to dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to initialize object   #002: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5L.c line 1638 in H5L_link_object(): unable to create new link to object
    major: Links
    minor: Unable to initialize object   #003: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5L.c line 1882 in H5L_create_real(): can't insert link
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Unable to insert object   #004: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5Gtraverse.c line 861 in H5G_traverse(): internal path traversal failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found   #005: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5Gtraverse.c line 641 in H5G_traverse_real(): traversal operator failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Callback failed   #006: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5L.c line 1685 in H5L_link_cb(): unable to create object
    major: Object header
    minor: Unable to initialize object   #007: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5O.c line 3015 in H5O_obj_create(): unable to open object
    major: Object header
    minor: Can't open object   #008: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5Doh.c line 293 in H5O__dset_create(): unable to create dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to initialize object   #009: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5Dint.c line 1044 in H5D__create(): unable to construct layout information
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to initialize object   #010: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5Dcompact.c line 212 in H5D__compact_construct(): compact dataset size is bigger than header message maximum size
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to initialize object HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.10) thread 0:   #000: /pub/devel/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.10-1/src/hdf5-1.8.10/src/H5D.c line 391 in H5Dclose(): not a dataset
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
```

This happens for all vector sizes >= 2^13 (8192). Which is puzzeling me since reading in is no problem with bigger files and 2^13 is still a rather small number so something must be fishi with my code.

Any help would be appreatiated.
yours
magu_

Comment: Not sure it will help but still: Assuming a `double` is 8 bytes wide, you have a "raw" data size of 8192*8 = 65536 (i.e. 64 KB), and in [H5Dcompact.c](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/src/H5Dcompact.c) you can read this comment: `Verify data size is smaller than maximum header message size (64KB) minus other layout message fields.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for the `H5D_COMPACT` parameter for [`H5Pset_layout`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5P.html#Property-SetLayout):

> Store raw data in the dataset object header in file. This should only
>   be used for datasets with small amounts of raw data. The raw data size
>   limit is 64K (65520 bytes). Attempting to create a dataset with raw
>   data larger than this limit will cause the H5Dcreate call to fail.

So if your doubles are 8 bytes, you've run into that limit.

You need to use one of the other storage options, contiguous or chunked.

Comment: Hm, yes this makes sense. Thx (both molbfnilo & gx_) for the answer. Now it does work (for now^^)