# Manage H5Pset_layout in R

Tags: r, hdf5, bioconductor

I'm working with a 4.6 Gb data.frame in R and I would like to save it in hdf5 format.
This is what I'm doing:

```
> print(object.size(A), units = "Gb")
    4.6 Gb

> library(rhdf5) 
> hd5_file="/home/usert/sim/sim.h5"
> h5createFile( hd5_file )
[1] TRUE 

h5write(A, hd5_file, "A")
```

I receive this error message:

> ```
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5D.c line 170 in H5Dcreate2(): unable to create dataset
>     major: Dataset
>     minor: Unable to initialize object
>   #001: H5Dint.c line 431 in H5D_create_named(): unable to create and link to dataset
>     major: Dataset
>     minor: Unable to initialize object
>   #002: H5L.c line 1640 in H5L_link_object(): unable to create new link to object
>     major: Links
>     minor: Unable to initialize object
>   #003: H5L.c line 1884 in H5L_create_real(): can't insert link
>     major: Symbol table
>     minor: Unable to insert object
>   #004: H5Gtraverse.c line 905 in H5G_traverse(): internal path traversal failed
>     major: Symbol table
>     minor: Object not found
>   #005: H5Gtraverse.c line 688 in H5G_traverse_real(): traversal operator failed
>     major: Symbol table
>     minor: Callback failed
>   #006: H5L.c line 1687 in H5L_link_cb(): unable to create object
>     major: Object header
>     minor: Unable to initialize object
>   #007: H5O.c line 3013 in H5O_obj_create(): unable to open object
>     major: Object header
>     minor: Can't open object
>   #008: H5Doh.c line 295 in H5O_dset_create(): unable to create dataset
>     major: Dataset
>     minor: Unable to initialize object
>   #009: H5Dint.c line 1035 in H5D_create(): unable to construct layout information
>     major: Dataset
>     minor: Unable to initialize object
>   #010: H5Dchunk.c line 443 in H5D_chunk_construct(): chunk size must be < 4GB
>     major: Dataset
>     minor: Unable to initialize object
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine[enter link description here][1]
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.7) thread 0:
>   #000: H5D.c line 391 in H5Dclose(): not a dataset
>     major: Invalid arguments to routine
>     minor: Inappropriate type
> ```

and (I suppose) I should set a storage option different from H5D_COMPACT, working with contiguous or chunked file as reported in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103779/cant-write-hdf5-file-with-vector-bigger-than-213) and in the [official reference manua](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5P.html#Property-SetLayout)l.

Is there a way to work with H5Pset_layout from R?

Comment: You'll probably have better luck asking at https://support.bioconductor.org

Comment: I am being thrown the same errors though I'm working with a much smaller dataset. Did you figure out how to solve this?